# Python -- Beautiful Soup -- Returning Information if a tag is empty or has values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I decided to learn Python since I now have more time (due to pandemic) and have been teaching myself Python.

I am trying to scrape tax rates from a site and can get almost everything I need. Below is a snippet of the code that comes out of my *Soup* variable as well as the relevant piece of Python.

Where I am having difficulty is I am finding the `option` tag along with the `data-alias` that is empty (""). However, if you look at the code below there are some `data-alias` stages that are not empty **(see UAE or Great Britain)**- they have some countries listed.

I am looking to get the `data-url` and country name from these as well.

How do I code this to get empty tags and non-empty tags as I am losing some required information?

Thanks,
Seth

**My code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

l=[]
r = requests.get("https://taxsummaries.pwc.com/")
c=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
all = soup.find_all("option", {"data-alias":""})
```

**Website Information:**

```html
<option data-alias="" data-id="c9ddd85e-f3dc-4661-a4cb-8101f4644871" data-url="https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/uganda">Uganda</option>
<option data-alias="" data-id="d21e8abe-784c-4617-a90e-5369b49a202f" data-url="https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/ukraine">Ukraine</option>
<option data-alias="UAE" data-id="9e3f5e7b-f110-47dd-95d8-3d8160466e4a" data-url="https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/united-arab-emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option data-alias="Great Britain
UK
Britain
Whales
Northern Ireland
England" data-id="3c42b2a9-7ed6-4b19-821d-5d78ef6f2b5d" data-url="https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/united-kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
```

Comment: hi there - many thanks Seth for stepping up the plate with this great question - it is an interesting pathway to many python-topics. Thanks - and keep up your journey to python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `{"data-alias":True}`. You can try it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
l=[]
r = requests.get("https://taxsummaries.pwc.com/")
c=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
options = soup.find_all('option', {"data-alias":True})
for each in options:
    print("country_name : " + str(each.text), " data-url : " + str(each['data-url']))
```

Output will be:

```
country_name : Albania  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/albania
country_name : Algeria  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/algeria
country_name : Angola  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/angola
country_name : Argentina  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/argentina
country_name : Armenia  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/armenia
country_name : Australia  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/australia
country_name : Austria  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/austria
country_name : Azerbaijan  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/azerbaijan
country_name : Bahrain  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/bahrain
country_name : Barbados  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/barbados
country_name : Belarus  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/belarus
country_name : Belgium  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/belgium
country_name : Bermuda  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/bermuda
country_name : Bolivia  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/bolivia
country_name : Bosnia and Herzegovina  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/bosnia-and-herzegovina
country_name : Botswana  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/botswana
country_name : Brazil  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/brazil
country_name : Bulgaria  data-url : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/bulgaria


and so on ......
```

For getting as a `list`:

```
for each in options:
    l.append( str(each.text)+ " : " + str(each['data-url']))
print(l)
```

Output will be:

```
['Albania : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/albania', 'Algeria : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/algeria', 'Angola : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/angola', 'Argentina : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/argentina', 'Armenia : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/armenia', 'Australia : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/australia', 'Austria : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/austria', 'Azerbaijan : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/azerbaijan', 'Bahrain : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/bahrain', 'Barbados : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/barbados', 'Belarus : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/belarus', 'Belgium : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/belgium', 'Bermuda : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/bermuda', 'Bolivia : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/bolivia', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/bosnia-and-herzegovina', 'Botswana : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/botswana', 'Brazil : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/brazil', 'Bulgaria : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/bulgaria', 'Cabo Verde : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/cabo-verde', 'Cambodia : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/cambodia', 'Cameroon, Republic of : https://taxsummaries.pwc.com:443/republic-of-cameroon',


and so on............]
```

Comment: Thank you Humayun! That worked perfectly! I am guessing the True statement just means -- return all data-alias tags? I am asl guessing that would work in any similar situation?

Comment: @SethMoskowitz Glad to help out, please consider to upvote and/or accept if it helped.[stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: many thanks fpr this interesting answer - youre great

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, which would also introduce you to some other Python topics of potential interest (as you mentioned you are learning):

```
all = soup.find_all("option", {"data-alias":True})

results=[]
for item in all:
   results.append({item.text:item['data-url']})
```

**Comments:**

- `soup.find_all("option", {"data-alias":True})` - this will find all
  `option` tags having a `data-alias` attribute, irrespective of its
  value
- `results` is a `list` to add the records in scope to
  (`results.append`)
- `{item.text:item['data-url']}` - this is a
  [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
  where the **key** is the country name (`item.text`) and the **value**
  is data-url attribute (`item['data-url']`)

An equivalent (and more compact) way of writing the results list is using the concept of [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
results=[{item.text:item['data-url']} for item in all]
```

Comment: Thank you! I will review the code you were and learn what I can from it. I appreciate the time you took to write this.

Comment: hi dear Obuz many many thanks for the answer and the great asset of additonal information you have provided within!  Great!!!